# Getting back to the first page in the stack in Flutter

Tags: flutter

In my Flutter app I want to get back to the home page by removing everything but the first page from the stack.

I've found two ways of doing it and they both seem to work but since I'm fairly new to Flutter I was wondering of one of these methods is best :-

```
Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);

Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, '/', (_) => false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use both of them.

But, in my own opinion (as I read the docs), in order to use the `pushNamedAndRemoveUntil` method, you need to name your routes.

On the other hand, If you do not use named routes, you can use the `popUntil` method. Because it's not using named routes and much simpler.

Comment: I haven't named my routes but it still seems to work. Maybe because it's the first page?

Comment: Yup, I think so. :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is `pushAndRemoveUntil`. There is a method like this available for you, if you don't want to use `named route` in your flutter app. Read about it [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorState/pushAndRemoveUntil.html).

So, now what you can do it:

```
// It accepts Route object, so we can use Material Page Route 
// We name your first page as HomePage, so don't get Confused
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context, 
   MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()), 
   (_) => false
);
```

Read about [MaterialPageRoute class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialPageRoute-class.html), and add it to your bucket, because it is a very useful thing, if you don't know about it already.